# Python pyppeteer, how to use a socks proxy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, tor, pyppeteer

I m trying to make my code use a socks proxy to browse a website with pyppeteer.
I couldn't find a way to make it work, here the code:

```
browser = await PYP.launch()

page= await browser.newPage()
await page.goto(url)
```

Is there any way to run PYP.launch with socks parameter? Like

```
browser = await PYP.launch({'args': ['--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:8080']})
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
args = ['--proxy-server=xx.xxxx.'] # xxx replaced by your proxy server
browser = await launch(headless = False,args = args)
```